# WinRT Sharing image receiver failure (Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, sharing

I'm having a hard time solving this one. What I'm trying to achieve is to make a sharing (receiver point) capability for my app so the app can process the images received.

1) the receiving *usually* works (I came to this problem from one app only)
 2) the "donor" app that fails to hookup with my app shares the image to another app (SkyDrive for example) just fine
 3) my manifest looks fine to me, the data format is registered and the file types are chosen

When I debug, I get the correct data format from the donor app (it's a "bitmap") and the bitmap format is ok too (png).

Further more, when I start the pool process, the IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType is fetched from the RandomAccessStreamReference and it shows the stream size correctly.

It is when I try to read this stream to the DataReader I get an exception:
   "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

Again, if I try to share an image from another app - it works just fine, and if I share from the "donor" app that is giving me issues to another app (not mine) it works too. So there must be a "trust" issue between the donor and my application set explicitly? Is that even possible?

This is the code snippet that should do all what needs to be done.

```
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)         
    {
        _sharedData = (ShareOperation)e.Parameter;

        try
        {
            IBuffer theBuffer = null;
            _sharedData.ReportStarted();

            if (_sharedData.Data.Contains("bitmap") || _sharedData.Data.Contains("Bitmap"))
            {
                var refe = await _sharedData.Data.GetBitmapAsync();

                using (var originalImageStream = await refe.OpenReadAsync())
                {
                    var dataReader = new DataReader(originalImageStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
    failure -->     await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint) originalImageStream.Size);
                    theBuffer = dataReader.ReadBuffer((uint) originalImageStream.Size);                      
                }
            }
            ....
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

and the manifest file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest">
  <Identity Name="enter your guid" Publisher="CN=author" Version="1.0.0.2" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>My App</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Author</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\LogoForStore.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Prerequisites>
    <OSMinVersion>6.2.1</OSMinVersion>
    <OSMaxVersionTested>6.2.1</OSMaxVersionTested>
  </Prerequisites>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="MyApp.App">
      <VisualElements DisplayName="MyApp" Logo="Assets\Logo.png" SmallLogo="Assets\SmallLogo.png" Description="MyApp" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#464646" ToastCapable="false">
        <DefaultTile ShowName="allLogos" WideLogo="Assets\WideLogo.png" ShortName="MyApp" />
        <SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
        <InitialRotationPreference>
          <Rotation Preference="landscape" />
          <Rotation Preference="landscapeFlipped" />
        </InitialRotationPreference>
      </VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.accountPictureProvider" />
        <Extension Category="windows.cameraSettings" />
        <Extension Category="windows.shareTarget">
          <ShareTarget>
            <SupportedFileTypes>
              <FileType>.png</FileType>
              <FileType>.jpg</FileType>
              <FileType>.gif</FileType>
            </SupportedFileTypes>
            <DataFormat>Bitmap</DataFormat>
            <DataFormat>StorageItems</DataFormat>
          </ShareTarget>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Any idea would be greatly appreciated!

M.